# jQuery.post() failure callback function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Let's say I've a code:

```
$.post("test.php", function(data) {
   alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
});
```

Is there any way to check if the request have failed (e.g. due to the timeout)?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Yes there is, from the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/):

```
$.post("test.php", function(data) {
   alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
})
.fail(function() { 
   alert("error"); 
})
```

Update: drake7077: "error is deprecated as of jquery 1.8, use .fail()"

Comment: .error is only supported on .post in jQuery v1.5 and later (as noted in the documented link).

Comment: Is there a way to get the error (apart from falling back to ajax)?

Answer (score 4):

Two possibilities:

1. You can register an "ajax error" general callback, which will be called when any ajax operation fails:

   ```
   $(document).ajaxError(function(event, jqXHR, settings, exception) { ... });
   ```
2. You can fall back to `$.ajax()` instead and include your own error handler directly.

*edit* — @amosrivera is right - the new "Deferred" return values allow for introduction of handlers. Those are available with jQuery 1.5 and newer.